# Python re.sub() is not replacing every match

Tags: python, regex, string, replace, capturing-group

I'm using Python 3 and I have two strings: `abbcabb` and `abca`. I want to remove every double occurrence of a **single character**. For example:

`abbcabb` should give `c` and `abca` should give `bc`.

I've tried the following regex ([here](https://regex101.com/r/94iSeB/2/)):

```
(.)(.*?)\1
```

But, it gives wrong output for first string. Also, when I tried another one ([here](https://regex101.com/r/94iSeB/3/)):

```
(.)(.*?)*?\1
```

But, this one again gives wrong output. What's going wrong here?

---

The python code is a print statement:

```
print(re.sub(r'(.)(.*?)\1', '\g<2>', s)) # s is the string
```

Comment: Explain the logic behind the results you want. Are you saying that if there are an even number of occurrences of the character, then you don't want it at all, and if there are an odd number, you want exactly one in the output? Do you actually care about the output order, or do you just want to know which characters have an odd number of occurrences ?

Comment: What _exactly_ do you mean to "every double occurrence"? "All characters which occur more than once in the string"? "All characters with a neighbor of the same value"?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel You're right. I want just one if the repetition is odd. And, the order is optional.

Comment: So that we're clear: putting both inputs together, `abbcabbabca`, should give `b` (since the two `c`s cancel), not `cbc`?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel yes, you're right.

Comment: Well, I tried to guess something else :) but if that really is the problem you're trying to solve, then regexes are really not what you want and @jon has it right.

Comment: clearly a case where you had a problem, you're using regexes and now you have 2 problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site explains it well, hover and use the explanation section.

`(.)(.*?)\1` Does not remove or match every double occurance. It matches 1 character, followed by anything in the middle sandwiched till that same character is encountered again.

so, for `abbcabb` the "sandwiched" portion should be `bbc` between two `a`

EDIT:
You can try something like this instead without regexes:

```
string = "abbcabb"
result = []
for i in string:
    if i not in result:
        result.append(i)
    else:
        result.remove(i)
print(''.join(result))
```

Note that this produces the "last" odd occurrence of a string and not first.

For "first" known occurance, you should use a counter as suggested in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53790862/10618540) . Just change the condition to check for odd counts. `pseudo code(count[letter] %2 == 1)`

Comment: Thanks! So, the regex actually skips to look again at `bbc` when it removes the `a`'s.

Comment: bingo. or more precisely, the re.sub should be thought of as two steps. the regex first matches everything it can in one go on the entire string, which means `abbca` and `bb`, and only then the replacement step happens. @rv7

Comment: I'm using regex because the length of string is guaranteed to be below 50. So, I thought looping wouldn't be the proper way to handle them.

Comment: regexes have to effectively scan or loop through your text under the wraps anyways. You can have a much more reliable output avoiding regexes in this setup if your goal is just to remove occurance pairs. @rv7

Answer (score 3):

It can be solved without regular expression, like below

```
>>>''.join([i for i in s1 if s1.count(i) == 1])
'bc'
>>>''.join([i for i in s if s.count(i) == 1])
'c'
```

Comment: This looks for unique characters; for characters with an odd count, modify the condition for the `.count` check accordingly (`s.count(i) % 2 == 1` for example).

Comment: sure @KarlKnechtel, i will modify  it soon Thanks for notifying :)

Comment: works, but using count repeatedly in a list comprehension loops over all elements each time: o(n**2). Gave me the idea to answer myself

Answer (score 2):

`re.sub()` doesn't perform overlapping replacements. After it replaces the first match, it starts looking after the end of the match. So when you perform the replacement on

```
abbcabb
```

it first replaces `abbca` with `bbc`. Then it replaces `bb` with an empty string. It doesn't go back and look for another match in `bbc`.

If you want that, you need to write your own loop.

```
while True:
    newS = re.sub(r'(.)(.*?)\1', r'\g<2>', s)
    if newS == s:
        break
    s = newS
print(newS)
```

[DEMO](https://ideone.com/MdK06d)

Comment: On reflection, I *think* how OP wants it to work is that the entire `abbcabb` is matched by the regex: an opening `abb`, a single character, and then a closing `abb` which matches the opening pattern.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I disagree, OPs group is only one character long. That cannot match `abb`

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions doesn't seem to be the ideal solution

- they don't handle overlapping so it it needs a loop (like in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53790735/6451573)) and it creates strings over and over (performance suffers)
- they're overkill here, we just need to count the characters

I like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53790819/6451573), but using `count` repeatedly in a list comprehension loops over all elements each time.

It can be solved without regular expression and without `O(n**2)` complexity, only `O(n)` using `collections.Counter`

- first count the characters of the string very easily & quickly
- then filter the string testing if the count matches using the counter we just created.

like this:

```
import collections

s = "abbcabb"

cnt = collections.Counter(s)

s = "".join([c for c in s if cnt[c]==1])
```

(as a bonus, you can change the count to keep characters which have 2, 3, whatever occurrences)

Comment: Yes, this general approach is best in the long run - hence the hint in my answer. (Un?)fortunately on modern machines it takes fairly long strings for this to become noticeable :)

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: based on the comment exchange - if you're just concerned with the parity of the letter counts, then you *don't want regex* and instead want an approach like @jon's recommendation. (If you don't care about order, then a more performant approach with very long strings might use something like `collections.Counter` instead.)

---

My best guess as to what you're trying to match is: "one or more characters - call this subpattern A - followed by a different set of one or more characters - call this subpattern B - followed by subpattern A again".

You can use `+` as a shortcut for "one or more" (instead of specifying it once and then using `*` for the rest of the matches), but either way you need to get the subpatterns right. Let's try:

```
>>> import re
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'(.+?)(.+?)\1')
>>> pattern.sub('\g<2>', 'abbcabbabca')
'bbcbaca'
```

Hmm. That didn't work. Why? Because with the first pattern not being greedy, our "subpattern A" can just match the first `a` in the string - it *does* appear later, after all. So if we use a greedy match, Python will backtrack until it finds as long of a pattern for subpattern A that still allows for the A-B-A pattern to appear:

```
>>> pattern = re.compile(r'(.+)(.+?)\1')
>>> pattern.sub('\g<2>', 'abbcabbabca')
'cbc'
```

Looks good to me.